# Loosely filtering an array

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following PHP variables:

```
$colors = array( 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'brown' );
$skey = 'ow';
```

How can I filter `$colors` using `$skey` to get an array which only contain 'yellow' and 'brown'?

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: function arraySearch( $array, $search ) { 
    foreach ($array as $a ) { 
        if(strstr( $a, $search)){ 
            echo $a;
        } 
      } 
    return false; 
    }
    arraySearch(array('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'brown'),"ow");

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php),

```
$results = array_filter($colors, function($var){ return strpos($var, 'ow') !== false; });
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/avaBXp)**.

Comment: That's neat. :) My answer will go off for that :)